# Use Express server to control a nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I have a node.js application which I use to interact with a REST API provided by another server. I would like to expose a web interface (html + css + javascript) using express.js in order to control the first application.

How can I let the browser talk to the server and let it make node.js actions like using http from that machine or writing to its filesystem? I tried using XMLHttpRequest, but HTTP requests are sent by my local PC instead of from my server.

The only solution I found is using XMLHttpRequest in the javascript of my web interface to invoke some middleware functions on my server, but I had some problems: when I make POST requests, I cannot read data from server. I used FormData and its append method to make the "body" of the POST request, then used body-parser in express to read that body, but it turns out to be always empty. Also tried changing the 'Content-Type' of the header.

Any suggestions? Any better solution than mine (I think it is not efficient)?

Comment: Using the nodeJS server as a "proxy" is the right approach, what went wrong with your version is hard to tell without code.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Jonas, using node server as proxy would be the right approach.

I'm providing sample code for both frontend as well as backend app. Hope this helps you.

- **Frontend App Code**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function sendData(data) {
        if (!data) {
          // lets define some dummy data for testing
          data = { somekey: "somevalue", anotherkey: "anothervalues" };
        }
        var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var FD = new FormData();

        // Push our data into our FormData object
        for (name in data) {
          FD.append(name, data[name]);
        }

        // Define what happens on successful data submission
        XHR.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
          alert("Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.");
          alert(event.target.responseText);
        });

        // Define what happens in case of error
        XHR.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
          alert("Oops! Something went wrong.");
        });

        // Set up our request
        XHR.open("POST", "http://path/to/your/nodejs/server/app");

        // Send our FormData object; HTTP headers are set automatically
        XHR.send(FD);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="sendData()">Send Test Request to the Server</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

- **Backend App code**

```
    const http = require('http'); 
    const express = require('express'); 
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
    const app = express(); 
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Yeah! Server is UP! Post some data'));

    app.post('/', (req, res) => {   
      // You'll see the posted data in req.body, simply for testing purpose return it back to the calling user   
      res.json(req.body || {}); 
    });

    const server = http.createServer(app); 
    server.listen(3000); 
    server.on('error', console.error); 
    server.on('listening', () => console.log('Listening on 3000')); 
    process.on('exit', (code) => console.warn('Server terminated with code=' + code));
```

Please note that for this backend app to run, you must have installed following npm packages: express, body-parser

Comment: req.body turned out to be an empty object for me. I checked if the FD object was empty and it was not, so I don't understand where I am wrong...